# Grails Twitter Bootstrap Plugin Pagination Display is Messed Up

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grails, pagination

I am using Twitter BootStrap Plugin compile 3.3.5 with Grails 2.3.11 and I've added the pagination fix in `Config.groovy`. When I go to display a list of records (Index action) the pagination seems to be messed up. It displays a vertical block of page numbers instead of the sleek pagination of default Grails 2.3.11. I have the pagination with bootstrap below:

[image: Paginate Issue]

This doesn't seem to be what it looks like. I figured it would display horizontally and not take up so much space on the page like it is now. Normal pagination shown for reference:
[image: Normal]

Can anyone confirm that what I have attached is default behaviour of the plugin? In any case, how can I fix this issue?

Line in `Config.groovy`
`grails.plugins.twitterbootstrap.fixtaglib = true`

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested:

Some more researching has me understanding that I have to override the twitter bootstrap plugin pagination code. I don't want to do that. So I ended up with a *workaround* of manually installing bootstrap into my application (added relevant css and js links in my gsp files). I am still interested to know if what was asked in the OP is possible, however I am now able to take advantage of the bootstrap v4 styles which is a plus to me.